# SignatureDoesNotMatch in S3 using play-s3 and Play Framework 2.5 - Scala

Tags: java, scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, playframework

I am having the following issue, when Trying to retrieve a File from S3 using [play-s3](https://github.com/Kaliber/play-s3) but it looks like in the GET

> version used "net.kaliber" %% "play-s3" % "8.0.0"

```
fly.play.s3.S3Exception: Problem accessing S3. Status 403, code SignatureDoesNotMatch, message 'SignatureDoesNotMatch'

Problem accessing S3. Status 403, code SignatureDoesNotMatch, message 'SignatureDoesNotMatch'
Original xml:
Some(<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAI3DOSLNJC4YGPZSQ</AWSAccessKeyId><StringToSign>AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20160627T212133Z
20160627/eu-west-1/s3/aws4_request
f8795580f6de5742706adab4ca6c89f8bfa9565b1e0c837a54297a2dcd8114df</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>0dd99e84f2424d8d46dcff6119a9e34fa049489106149214caefe0fc1bd2d213</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes>41 57 53 34 2d 48 4d 41 43 2d 53 48 41 32 35 36 0a 32 30 31 36 30 36 32 37 54 32 31 32 31 33 33 5a 0a 32 30 31 36 30 36 32 37 2f 65 75 2d 77 65 73 74 2d 31 2f 73 33 2f 61 77 73 34 5f 72 65 71 75 65 73 74 0a 66 38 37 39 35 35 38 30 66 36 64 65 35 37 34 32 37 30 36 61 64 61 62 34 63 61 36 63 38 39 66 38 62 66 61 39 35 36 35 62 31 65 30 63 38 33 37 61 35 34 32 39 37 61 32 64 63 64 38 31 31 34 64 66</StringToSignBytes><CanonicalRequest>GET
/test%C2%ADtest%C2%ADtest%C2%ADfilipe/1234.jpg
```

My code looks like this:

```
  val result = S3(bucketName)
    .get("1234.jpg")

  val file = Await.result(result, 10 seconds)
  log.info(""+file)
```

The application.conf has the following properties, which aI know for a fac are valid ones:

```
aws.accessKeyId="AAaAAAAAAA"  //not the real one
aws.secretKey="AAAAAAAA"      //not the real one of course
aws.bucket="filipe-bucket"
s3.region="eu-west-1"
```

(the region is correct!)

I spent quite a bit of time trying to figure out what the issue might be - does anybody has clue about it?

Is this an issue perhaps with the date sent in the signature, they say it should match the date of the request:

```
host:s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
x-amz-date:20160627T214556Z
```

Note that I made the request at 11:45pm(I am CEST), and the time here is:

```
 x-amz-date:20160627T214556Z
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-date-handling.html

Comment: Wild guess here, but could you try with a "simpler" bucket name (this one would be encoded as `filipe%3Dbicket` and could be messing with the signature)? Try something like `filipe-bucket`.

Comment: Hi @marcospereira - it is actually filipe-bucket
I missed typed.